# How to proof that $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{e^h-1}{h} = 1$ using the definition $e = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$?

Tags: limits, definition, constants

In other words, how I can prove that these two definitions of $e$ is equal? I saw these two definitions while trying to find proofs for $\frac{d}{dx}e^x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}\ln x$; some use the former definition, and others used the latter, and I cannot find a proof that these two definitions are equal. So how do I prove this? Thank you!

Comment: Is that h there n?

Comment: Yes, sorry for typo

Comment: Use the definition to prove $e^x=\sum\frac{x^n}{n!}$ and then it's obvious.

Comment: Note that the definition of $e$ does not immediately yield a definition of $e^h$.

Comment: How do I proof that?

Comment: @user2345215 isn't that from taylor polynomial? but can I proof that using only the definitions?

Answer (score 5):

From $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ easily follows $e^x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ for $x>0$.

If you prove that even $e=\lim\limits_{n\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$, then $e^x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$ also for $x<0$.

Expand the expression inside the limit:
$$\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\frac{x^k}{n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$

For a fixed $k$ we have $\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k}\to1$, so it's not hard to see $$\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\to\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
using the fact that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}<\infty$ and that $\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k}<1$.

Your limit follows easily from this (in fact, we found the whole Taylor series for $e^x$).

Comment: Why for fixed $k$ we have ${n(n-1)...(n-k+1)\over n^k}\to 1$?

Comment: Or do you mean $< 1$

Comment: Maybe it is the notation that I don't recognize, or we were not taught about this, or I forgot...

Comment: $a_n\to K$ means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=K$, is that what you are asking?

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now.

Comment: @user2345215 this may be naive by how does the first statement easily follow? I've always taken that to be the definition of $e^x$ as opposed to following from the definition of $e$

Comment: @DanZimm It depends on how you define exponentiation. If you define $a^b$ as $e^{b\ln a}$, then you obviously need to have a definition of $e^x$. But $a^b$ can also be defined as $\lim\limits_{p/q \to b}\sqrt[q]{a^p}$, which can be viewed as more natural. In that case $e=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n\implies e^x=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^{nx}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac xn)^n$.

Comment: @user2345215 right but how do you get that last equality?

Comment: @DanZimm Uhm, $n\mapsto\frac nx$? (for $x>0$)

Comment: @user2345215 oh wow I'm silly, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here is that taking $e^x$ isn't properly defined. The definition $e = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ is something I have always found dissatisfying. Here is an alternative approach that will also fulfill your desire for proofs of your derivative formulas.

Define log function $\mathrm{ln}: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows: $$\mathrm{ln}(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$$
From this everything follows. We have immediately properties such as $\mathrm{ln}(ab) = \mathrm{ln}(a) + \mathrm{ln}(b)$. We also have by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus that $\mathrm{ln}'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. Note also that since $f:t\mapsto 1/t$ is strictly positive, $\mathrm{ln}$ is one-to-one. It is also not hard to show that $\mathrm{ln}$ is surjective. Thus, define $e$ as the unique positive real such that $\mathrm{ln}(e) = 1$. One can check that the natural log of your limit is one as well directly.

Additionally, define the exponential function $\exp(x)$ as the inverse of $\mathrm{ln}$. We can define then exponentiation of a real number $a^b = \exp(b \;\mathrm{ln}( a))$. Now this may seem circular: isn't exponentiation already defined? Only for $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. One can check that our definition of exponentiation confirms that $a^n = a*a*\ldots*a$ using the property that $\exp(a+b) = \exp(a)\exp(b)$ (proven by taking the inverse of both sides, essentially).

To take the derivative of $\exp(x)$, we use the chain rule:
$$1 = \frac{d}{dx}x = \frac{d}{dx} \mathrm{ln}(\exp(x)) = \frac{exp'(x)}{exp(x)}$$
Thus, $\exp'(x) = \exp(x)$.

One final note: Since $\mathrm{ln}(e) = 1$, we have that $\exp(x) = e^x$.